# Como usar AngularJS en Fiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

Buenas!

Querria hacer una prueba con un código en JsFiddle con Angular. Esoty intentandolo metiendo el link en "External resources" pero no hay manera de que me lo coja. Alguien me puede decir como es la manera correcta de hacerlo o decirme el link a un tutorial? Lo estuve buscando pero no lo encontre.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando empieces tu proyecto le das en el engrane del archivo `javascript` y te desplegara un menu de opciones y en `FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS` busca la versión de angular y listo, el menu de opciones saldrá mas o menos 
como en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro ejemplo es el siguiente, nota que se muestra la versión de angular que se esta utilizando en el ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno espero que te funcione.

Comment: Justo acabo de encontrarlo! Pero muchisimas gracias :) Y espero que esto le sirva al siguiente ;-)